# What should I understand "available electronically" in this context?

Tags: word-meaning, translation

In the sentence:

> I needed a language that would run on the machines in our Linux lab as well as on the Windows and Macintosh platforms most students have at home. I wanted it to be free and **available electronically,** so that students could use it at home regardless of their income.

What should I understand the meaning of  **available electronically**?
Does this mean, a language should be **downloadable**? Or, should be used **anywhere with computers**?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It should not require fixed physical media, e.g. only run from CD. It could be available on the network, downloaded, or even distributed on XD flash cards, for example, that can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence sets out a number of parameters in addition to **available electronically**  and most readers would conclude this means downloadable.

All computer information is stored and processed digitally so to make the distinction of the language being *free* and available *electronically* the author is effectivley saying that it can be easily obtained by the students using the computers they have at home with an implication of *only* using the computers they have at home.

Given that the students computers are *at their homes* then the common factor for them is the ability to connect to the Internet and download software.